# How Amazon holds exclusive rights to the Elastic IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address, elastic-ip

When I allocate an Elastic IP, it stays with me forever (until I remove it).

This also means, no one can ever use this IP address in the entire world. And you can see there is not DNS or stuff. Its is a straight forward IP address reachable from browser.

How does Amazon block the IP to itself? In other words, how does Amazon hold an IP address so that no one can use it.

Answer (score 7):

Same way anybody else can:

https://www.apnic.net/get-ip/faqs/obtaining-resources/

> **Can I buy IP addresses?**
>
> IP addresses are not for sale, instead, they are public resources
>   administered by the Internet Numbers Registry System for the entire
>   Internet community. IP addresses delegated by the Regional registries,
>   such as APNIC are not "owned" by the Members. IP addresses will be
>   reclaimed by APNIC when the Membership is terminated.
>
> **Why does APNIC require so much detailed information about my network?**
>
> APNIC must ensure that address space, which is a shared public
>   resource, is managed responsibly in the region. APNIC needs detailed
>   information so that it can properly evaluate whether your plans
>   conform to agreed addressing policy and are consistent with the goals
>   of global Internet management.